# Changing SharePoint 2013 theme design using online theme

Tags: 2013, css, theme, design

I am new in web designing and in SharePoint . I want to change the SharePoint 2013 theme using online theme. What is your advice for me? Also, I want to change the layout of contents to be tidy.actually, my manager want me to download an online theme and apply it on the site of their organization.

I saw multiple themes but they have different pages and when I publish them in SharePoint it doesn't change anything.

Can anyone help me step by step? what should I do?

Comment: My honest advice, do as minimal branding as possible. At the moment SPOnline Modern Experiences have blocked **all** branding. So when your manager says: "*And now we go Office365*", you have to reply with: "*Then, most of the work I did can go straight to the bin*"